# Backbone.iobind should it be a node package or bower package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js

I am trying to use backbone.iobind so I can bind Socket.io events to models and collections.

I see there is a npm package https://www.npmjs.org/package/backbone.iobind and a bower package http://bower.io/search/?q=backbone.iobind They both have the same docs.

This may be a silly question, but it's the little things that can confuse me.

So my question is, by choosing one is it just preference? Whats the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference will be installation medium. One is pulled in the NPM, the other Bower. The same package, multiple package managers.

It's worth noting that Bower is a *front end* package manager, whilst NPM is a *back end* package manager, so the scripts will be downloaded and positioned in a way that suits those mediums.

Comment: Yeah I had to think about that, in terms of what each did, I realize NPM did backend management and bower frontend. I guess I am more confused with backbone.iobind itself. You say it needs to be positioned to suit those mediums, according to the docs it seems it should be included on the front end correct?

Comment: Maybe it depends on the project, is what you're saying. So this helps Ill need to do more research on backbone.iobind and how I can incorporate it with my project.

Comment: But is there a chance it's used on both. Or is it most likely either front end or backend not both, just one?

Comment: It appears that it's a front end tool, although it clearly has ties with the back end, the README certainly doesn't make it obvious that it belongs on NPM at all.

Comment: Okay thanks thats all I needed. not a fantastic question but I am curious. thnx